# Chain ExceptT with different Left in do block

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads, monad-transformers

I have a couple of computations to run which throw different kinds of exceptions. How can I chain them in a do block without evaluating every single one and then pattern matching the result as `Either ex result`?

```
type IntComp ex = ExceptT ex IO Int

local :: IntComp IOException
local = ExceptT $ map length <$> tryIO (readFile "file")

web :: IntComp WebException
web = ExceptT $ map length <$> tryAny (getWebsite "file")

comp :: (Exception ex) => IntComp ? -> IntComp ? -> IntComp ?
comp local web = ExceptT $ do
res1 <- local
res2 <- web
return (res1 + res2)
```

Since they all have an instance of `Exception` I would think there must be some way to write a `comp` function in similar fashion?

Comment: Since they throw different kinds of exceptions, this is going to be more troublesome.

Comment: I see. After some reading it seems I am trying to emulate functionality of `MonadThrow`?

Comment: For such a simple example, just use [`withExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#v:withExceptT) to change the type of one or both exceptions - `withExceptT Left` and `withExceptT Right` are 'simple' choices.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two exception types `EOne` and `ETwo`, you could do it like this:

```
twoExceptions :: ExceptT (Either EOne ETwo) m a
twoExceptions = do
    fmapL Left computationThatFailsWithEOne -- :: ExceptT EOne m b
    fmapL Right computationThatFailsWithETwo -- :: ExceptT ETwo m c
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comp :: (Exception ex1, Exception ex2) => IntComp ex1 -> IntComp ex2 -> IntComp SomeException
comp local web = do
    res1 <- withExceptT toException local
    res2 <- withExceptT toException web
    return (res1 + res2)
```